# Connecting to SMTP using net Library Node

Tags: node.js, sockets, smtp, telnet, email-validation

Hi I am trying to ping the email address for that I need to connect to the SMTP server. I am using node net library. Below is what I am doing,

```
socket.connect(options, function () {
  console.log('Connected')
  socket.write('HELO here.com \r')
  socket.write('MAIL FROM: <me@here.com> \r')
  socket.write('RCPT TO: <not.a.valid.emailaddress.1234qa@gmail.com> \r')
})
socket.on('data', function (data) {
 console.log('Received: ' + data)
})
socket.on('close', function () {
 console.log('Connection closed')
})
socket.on('error', function (exception) {
 console.log(exception)
})
socket.on('timeout', function () {
 console.log('timeout!')
})
```

I do get response for the first HELO command, but nothing after.
Is there anything which I am missing? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I sort that out by myself, might be helpful to someone who's facing the same issue.
I was missing the line breaks. So the code will look like this;

```
socket.connect(options, function () {
  console.log('Connected')
  socket.write('\r\n')
  socket.write('HELO here.com \r\n')
  socket.write('MAIL FROM: <me@here.com> \r\n')
  socket.write('RCPT TO: <not.a.valid.email@gmail.com> \r\n')
})
```